# How do I create array of drawable automatically

Tags: java, android

I have while loop that create my String array like below

```
String[] imageId = {"R.drawable.img0","R.drawable.img1"};
```

but I want store it into Integer Array

```
Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.img20,R.drawable.img1};
```

Comment: You can't go from the string to the integer, but you can just get the integers in your loop.

Comment: Use reflection, instead of using such an array

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it without using reflection is to create a mapping for all drawables you have (since you know all your drawables in resources at compile time):

```
static final Map<String, Integer> MAPPING;
static {
    final Map<String, Integer> tempMapping = new HashMap<>();
    tempMapping.put("R.drawable.img0", R.drawable.img20);
    tempMapping.put("R.drawable.img1", R.drawable.img1);
    tempMapping.put([your other drawables]);
    MAPPING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(valuesByName);
}
```

After that, depending on your app's logic, you construct your array of drawables' names, and convert it to an array of drawables' ids using the map.

Comment: sorry but how can I use this?

Comment: @Amir.KH realized it wasn't a complete idea, edited my answer. Please check and tell me if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I want store it into Integer Array

Here's an example to save the array variables in integer:

```
int[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1, // index 0
               R.drawable.image2, // index 1
               R.drawable.image3, // index 2
               R.drawable.image4 // index 3
               };
```

To get the array value back:

```
int drawable1 = imageId[0] // returns R.drawable.image1
int drawable2 = imageId[1] // returns R.drawable.image2
int drawable3 = imageId[2] // returns R.drawable.image3
int drawable4 = imageId[3] // returns R.drawable.image4
```

Hope this example helps you a lot.